# Is it possible to scale an rectangle in a specified direction in SVG?

Tags: svg

This is my SVG code:

```html
<svg>
<path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.72 0.60)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.00 78.87" />
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 79.11 0.48)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.24 78.87" />
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.60 79.35)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 78.75 0.00"/>
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 39.38 11.85)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.24 67.02"/>
 <rect width="77.9122" height="38.4176" transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.08 40.33)"  fill="#000000" stroke="#000000">
 </rect>
</svg>
```

The rectangle starts at (1.08, 40.33) - as specified in the 'transform' attribute.

When i animate the rectangle using the following 'animateTransform' tag, i get the following image:

```html
<svg>
<path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.72 0.60)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.00 78.87" />
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 79.11 0.48)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.24 78.87" />
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.60 79.35)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 78.75 0.00"/>
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 39.38 11.85)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.24 67.02"/>
 <rect width="77.9122" height="38.4176" transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.08 40.33)"  fill="#000000" stroke="#000000">
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" additive="sum" from="1 1" to="1 0.5" begin="0s" dur="3s"/> </rect>
</svg>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1brYH.png)

But i want to scale the rectangle upwards, (i.e.) the resultant scaled image to be like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtYMG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could translate the rect at the same time as you scale it. Like this...

```html
<svg>
<path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.72 0.60)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.00 78.87" />
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 79.11 0.48)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.24 78.87" />
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.60 79.35)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 78.75 0.00"/>
 <path transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 39.38 11.85)" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 0.00 0.00 L 0.24 67.02"/>
 <rect width="77.9122" height="38.4176" transform="matrix(1.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 1.08 40.33)"  fill="#000000" stroke="#000000">
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" additive="sum" from="1 1" to="1 1.5" begin="0s" dur="3s"/>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" additive="sum" from="0 0" to="0 -13" begin="0s" dur="3s"/>
 </rect>
</svg>
```